# Embed SWT Composite into C# application

Tags: java, c#, swt, ole

I've got a Java application that uses SWT as its widget toolkit.

I've also got a Windows C# application.

I'd like a way to draw an SWT Composite into this C# application.

I can think of two ways to do this:

- **Handles:** Since SWT is based on the native windowing toolkit, it seems like there should be a way to create a Composite in the C# application, pass the native pointer to the Java application, and then control the Composite from there.
- **OLE:** Since SWT can definitely consume OLE components, maybe there's also a way for it to present itself as an OLE component?

Anybody have any tips on how I can accomplish this?  I'm not afraid of complicated communication between the Java and C# on startup, but I'm really hoping to be able to control the Composite from Java seamlessly once it is set up.

Comment: did you try [ikvm](http://www.ikvm.net/) project(compile to .net dll and then use the dll)? another option is [jnbridge](http://jnbridge.com/software/jnbridgepro/developer-center/guides#JinN). [JnBridge Demo:Embedding Java GUI elements inside a .NET Windows Form](http://jnbridge.com/guides/J_in_N_embedding.pdf)

Comment: I thought on another option, but this option is relevant only if you just want to composite the SWT inside the winform. you can start your SWT application in other process, then get the process main window handle and set your winform as a parent. edit: [example for winform hosting other process window](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project)

Comment: JNBridge works for Swing/AWT, but does not work for SWT.  ikvm might work, but my application makes heavy usage dynamic classloading and the latest features in Java 8, and I am hoping to "add a feature" rather than change the application's architecture.

Comment: I think your "winform hosting" is *exactly* what I'm looking to do.  I'll dig deeper and report back.  Thanks!!

Comment: @OldFox Your winform tutorial was exactly what I needed, and it works great.  If you post it as an answer, I'll accept.  Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: hi Ned, sorry for the late answer. I was busy and I did not want to write an answer that it includes a general solution. so i created a repository in github with a simple solution. this repository also demonstrate how to communicate between the processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put your SWT composite inside your winform you can start the SWT application in new process and then use Process.MainWindowHandle to get the child process window handle.

This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9123/Hosting-EXE-Applications-in-a-WinForm-project) provide an example to composite another process.

[This](https://github.com/OldFox1/CompositeSWTInWinform/tree/master/PerentWindow) link is a specific solution for SWT inside winform and winform inside winform(change the process to start...).

In the solution I also demonstrate a way to communicate between the processes through the std-in/out.(there are a lot of questions about it)

Hint:
The code in the repository is not a production code! (C# and Java)

I just want to provide a demo. when i have time, i will refactor the code...

Comment: Above and beyond!  I used your original link to make a similar demo inside my application.  Feel free to refactor for other users of course, but your original hint was everything I needed to go off to the races!