# C# process to read a java process' outputstream without using sockets or IDL/CORBA or file or database or JNI

Tags: java, c#, service, communication

I need to add a service to my web application which opens a java process from command line and communicates through input/output streams of that jvm thread instead of using IDL or sockets or database or files. Is there such connection between processes, which is very close to pure java?

C# webserver opens helloworld.jar and writes 1M bytes to console of it(console.in), then waits for console.out. I've read that command line arguments cannot go beyond kilobytes level. Maybe streams can go megabytes if there is such communication?

Communicating with only strings would be ok but using objects themselves would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639592/embed-swt-composite-into-c-sharp-application/28783254#28783254) answer I demonstrate the way to `IPC` using stdin/out between `executiable-jar`(`STW` application) and a `Winform` application.

The answer was linked into a solution I [made](https://github.com/OldFox1/CompositeSWTInWinform/tree/master/PerentWindow).

To read and write into the application you use the methods: `WriteLine` and `OutputDataReceived` (a `Process` methods, [see this class](https://github.com/OldFox1/CompositeSWTInWinform/blob/master/PerentWindow/Controls/ProcessStdCommunicator.cs)).

In the `Java` process you use `Scanner` to read and `Println` to write.([this is the java class](https://github.com/OldFox1/CompositeSWTInWinform/blob/master/PerentWindow/SimpleStdWriter.java))

The communication is through strings. You can serialize your objects into json and then pass them.(Using `Json.net` and `Gson`)

Comment: I just figured I can use java web services but this looks good too. Thanks.